# Can we measure color of an object in a silicon box?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, spectroscopy

Suppose we have an object $A$ in a silicon box. Let there also be a reference object $R$ with known spectrum of reflection in the same box. Silicon is known to be opaque in visible spectral range. Using the ranges of spectrum where the box is transparent (e.g. IR), can we deduce color (i.e. spectrum in visible range) of object $A$ without destroying the box?

In other words, can we deduce reflection coefficient at some wavelength $\lambda$ using only light of some other wavelengths not too close to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe not.

If "color" is the result of the reflectivity of an object across the range of 400 nm to 800 nm, and the silicon box is opaque across that range of wavelengths (essentially no transmission below 1100 nm), then you cannot expect to reconstitute the spectrum of the unknown object.

Comment: But why is snow blue? Because of absorption in the infrared. What causes the index of refraction and dispersion of water and glass? It is due to resonance frequencies in the ultraviolet. Things are connected.

Comment: @Pieter but you cannot deduce something about the material behind the absorbing material when that absorption is (almost) perfect. And you cannot know the exact location of absorptive resonances (especially in a complex system) based on the shape of their absorption "far away". To prove otherwise you would have to show the math - including error propagation.